# jQuery function works only when debugging

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  /*
   * Selectors function
   * Write the queries using .on()
  */
   $(document).on("click", ".categ", function() {
     console.log("#category-wrapper"+this.id);
       $("#books-wrapper"+this.id).html("");
       $("#chapters-wrapper").html("");
       $("#examples-wrapper").html("");
       $("#contributor").hide();
       ajax_loader(this);
       Dajaxice.website.books(function(data) {
           Dajax.process(data);
           ajax_loader("clear");
        }, {category_id: $(this).attr('id')});
    });
```

HTML code

```
<nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
    <div class="mp-level">
    <img src="{% static 'website/images/scilab-app-logo.svg' %}" class="full-width padding-logo" />
    <h2 class="icon icon-world" >Categories</h2>
    <ul>
    <div id="category-wrapper">
    {% for cate in catg %}
        <li id="categories" class="icon icon-arrow-left">
            <a href ="#" id={{ cate.id }} class="categ"> {{ cate.category_name }} </a>
                <div id="books-wrapper{{ cate.id }}" class="catbook"></div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Click function is working when I'm debugging( books inside category loads when I click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IM6W.png)

[When I just normally open webpag, open navbar and click on category nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZTtC.png)

Comment: Try getting it so the developer tool is at bottom of the screen instead of to the right... it might just be because it's making your screen smaller. If that's the case, I'd suggest looking at media queries

Comment: Code is working while debugging but not otherwise. Also I've tried it in other browsers like firefox IE still no good.